# how to call this function in python

Tags: python, data-structures

When i run this, nothing shows up, even no error message either. So, i want to know what is wrong with this and how to call these functions correctly.(I guess something wrong when I call this function)

```
class BinHeap:
    def makeheap(self):
            self.heapList=[0];
            self.currentSize=0;

    def perUp(self,i):
            while i // 2 > 0:
                    if self.heapList[i]<self.heapList[i//2]:
                            tmp=self.heapList[i//2]
                            self.heapList[i//2]=self.heapList[i]
                            self.heapList[i]=tmp
                    i = i // 2

    def insert(self,k):
            self.heapList.append(k)
            self.currentSize = self.currentSize+1
            self.perUp(self.currentSize)

    def percDown(self,i):
            while (i * 2) <= self.currentSize:
                    mc = self.minChild(i)
            if self.heapList[i] > self.heapList[mc]:
                    tmp = self.heapList[i]
            self.heapList[i] = self.heapList[mc]
            self.heapList[mc] = tmp
            i = mc

    def minChild(self,i):
            if i * 2 + 1 > self.currentSize:
                    return i * 2
            else:
                        if self.heapList[i*2] < self.heapList[i*2+1]:
                            return i * 2
                    else:
                            return i * 2 + 1
    def delMin(self):
            retval = self.heapList[1]
            self.heapList[1] = self.heapList[self.currentSize]
            self.currentSize = self.currentSize - 1
            self.heapList.pop()
            self.percDown(1)
            return retval

    def buildHeap(self,alist):
            i = len(alist) // 2
            self.currentSize = len(alist)
            self.heapList = [0] + alist[:]
            while (i > 0):
                    self.percDown(i)
                    i = i - 1

bh=BinHeap()
bh.buildHeap([9,5,6,2,3])
print("BinHeap")
print(bh.delMin())
print(bh.delMin())
print(bh.delMin())
print(bh.delMin())
print(bh.delMin())
```

Comment: Python code blocks work on indentation; if that is the correct indentation, your code where you create an object of class `bh = BinHeap()` and afterwords is indented to be part of the class. Move that out, and you should start seeing some execution.

Answer (score 0):

Python is very particular about spacing.  You've messed up the whitespace/formatting.  Edit your code so that the last few lines have no spaces/tabs in front of it and you should, at least, get an error or two.

```
# This is a subroutine to be executed when called
def buildHeap(self, alist):
    i = len(alist) // 2
    self.currentSize = len(alist)
    self.heapList = [0] + alist[:]
    while (i > 0):
       self.percDown(i)
       i = i - 1       

# these are commands to be executed now
bh = BinHeap()
bh.buildHeap([9,5,6,2,3])
print(bh.delMin())
print(bh.delMin())
print(bh.delMin())
print(bh.delMin())
print(bh.delMin())
```

Comment: I know how the format should be, it because StackOverflow keeps asking me to adjust the format as it required or i cannot submit this question.

Comment: Then I don't think we can help you.  The code you're presenting irrespective of formatting will display, at least, some errors.  Go back to `print("hello world")` and work forward.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : No huge indentation problem in your code. 
"nothing shows up, even no error message either" .. That's for sure ! Your code is stucked in doing the while loop in buildHeap function ! It goes in the percDown function doing this :

```
while (i * 2) <= self.currentSize:
        mc = self.minChild(i)
```

And then , let the term , "looping back" to :

```
def minChild(self,i):
        if i * 2 + 1 > self.currentSize:

                return i * 2

        else:
                    if self.heapList[i*2] < self.heapList[i*2+1]:

                        return i * 2
                    else:
                        return i * 2 + 1
```

And it start doing this again and again not telling you nothing in the shell.
Ovviously I'm going to give you some advice 'bout it :

1) Use comments between your lines of code to clarify what you're doing.

```
a = b + c #It's stupid but "a" is equal to "b" plus "c"
```

2) Print function is your friend ! It can help you when shell "doesn't speak". 
I'm providing you some pieces of your code with print statements , just to see how can you work with it :

```
def buildHeap(self,alist):
        i = len(alist) // 2
        self.currentSize = len(alist)
        self.heapList = [0] + alist[:]
        while (i > 0):
                print 'something wrong ..'
                self.percDown(i)
                print 'ok'
                i = i - 1
def percDown(self,i):
        while (i * 2) <= self.currentSize:
                print 'we re in the perc_Down'
                mc = self.minChild(i)
                print 'end of min child min child'
        if self.heapList[i] > self.heapList[mc]:
                tmp = self.heapList[i]
        self.heapList[i] = self.heapList[mc]
        self.heapList[mc] = tmp
        i = mc

def minChild(self,i):
        if i * 2 + 1 > self.currentSize:
                print 'if my min child'
                return i * 2
                print 'maybe stuck here ..'
        else:
                    if self.heapList[i*2] < self.heapList[i*2+1]:
                        print '*'
                        return i * 2
                    else:
                        return i * 2 + 1
                        print '*'
```

3)Please don't do "if" statements like you do in the minChild function :
Just try to include the Statement in the first If ! Like :

```
#this is your organization 
if ... :                #1) if 
   #doing stuff 
else:                   #1) else
   if ... :                         #2) if
      #stuff again
   else:                            #2) else
      ....
 #try this one 
 if ... and ... :       #1) if .. and .. 2) if
```

Need again something different ? Well you can do the elif statement:

```
if x < y: 
    print ....
elif x > y: 
    print ....
else: 
    print ....
```

Solution in this way is more elegant and readable.
One more thing :
Build your " **init** " when doing a "function" class in Python. Every of your object will have the attributes described in the constructor like :

```
class BinHeap:
     def __init__(self):
         self.currentSize = 0
         self.heapList = []
```